# Integrando site e CRM?

Tags: ajax

Olá, gente.

Eu preciso integrar um site com o EspoCRM (que tem uma api no Postman). Todo mundo que se cadastrar no formulário do site, vai direto pras Leads do CRM, foi me passado que é pra fazer um POST (ajax), a questão é que eu não sei por onde começar a fazer a integração.

Alguém poderia me dizer qual é o melhor caminho?

Comment: Eu costumo usar python, mas dizem que o melhor caminho pra isso é php.

Comment: Caso opte pelo PHP (http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Você pode usar o próprio javascript para realizar o POST. Quando for efetuado o submit do formulário em tela com o javascript envie uma requisição HTTP para a URL do CRM e a informação chegará até eles..